# java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: Windows-1252/WinLatin 1

Tags: java, parsing, csv

When i parsed my CSV file this error is generated.My CSV file has the font type of Windows-1252/WinLatin 1. So i set the this as character set at the time of parsing. How can i solve this problem. My code is :

```
reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    new File(directory)),
                    Charset.forName("Windows-1252/WinLatin 1")), Configuration.CSV_SEPERATOR);
```

Comment: `Windows-1252` should be the same charset and recognised. Programatically - split by a slash if not found otherwise.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `windows-1252` instead of `Windows-1252`?

Comment: @jlordo I hope not. Of course, you can still try.

Comment: The canonical names for supported encodings in Oracle Java 7 are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Charset.forName("windows-1252")` or `Charset.forName("Cp1252")`, to avoid IllegalCharsetNameException.  (As McDowell said above.)